# How to send notifications from OneSignal to segment users in WordPress?

Tags: wordpress, onesignal

I am creating a PWA in WordPress, and I would like to send notifications to user segments using the different categories of posts. I have consulted the Onesignal [guide here](https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/web-push-wordpress-faq#section-how-do-i-categorize-users-and-send-notifications-to-specific-categories-of-users-).
I created the segments based on the tags, using the slug of the post WordPress categories.

I installed the OneSignal plugin and followed the suggestions of [this solution](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/category-wise-subscription/).

The form works correctly, segmenting users into users based on the category of their choice. I can not however make the sending of notifications work when a post of a certain category is sent, indeed adding in the `functions.php` the suggested code (see the attached code) is no longer sent any notification.

Where am I doing wrong?

I apologize for my uncertain English and I thank those who will pay attention to my question.
Thank you and greetings

```
/**
* Send notifications based on category, Onesignal
*/

add_filter('onesignal_send_notification', 'onesignal_send_notification_filter', 10, 4);

function onesignal_send_notification_filter($fields, $new_status, $old_status, $post)
{
    $categories = get_the_category($post->ID);

    // Change which segment the notification goes to, will always be the first category
    $fields['included_segments'] = array($categories[0]->name);
    return $fields;
}
```

Adding this code to the `functions.php` of my child theme no notification is more sent by OneSignal

Answer (score 1):

your segments name must be same as your categories name

example;
if you have category name "News" you should have segment "News" also

Comment: It works! Thanks a lot! I was wrong because I had not indicated the segments with the same name of the categories, but with the slug !!! Thanks again!